# Extract a line from a file with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

How do I write a `sed` script that scans the input file for "start" and finds the line containing "next" and displays the following line? Something like this:

```
[user]$ cat test.txt
start
next
This line should print
Ignore this


[user]$ display.sed test.txt
This line should print

[user]$ cat test1.txt
Ignore this
next
Ignore this
start
Ignore this
next
This line should print
Ignore this
next
Too late so ignore this too
start
Ignore this too

[user]$ display.sed test1.txt
This line should print
```

Comment: What if you have `next` and then `something` after the second `start`, should the script print `something` too or should it print only the 1st occurrence ?

Comment: It should print only the 1st occurrence after start+next.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a range (from 1st occurrence of `start` to end of file) and `d`elete all lines in that range that don't match `next`. If a line matches, read in the `n`ext line, `p`rint it then `q`uit:

```
sed -n '/start/,${
/next/!d;n;p;q
}' infile
```

I guess what you actually want is a file `display.sed` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf

/start/,${
/next/!d;n;p;q
}
```

Comment: it gives me an unterminated 's' command. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I wrote the following: #!/bin/sed -f  then your code that you just posted.

Comment: if the file name is passed as an argument beside the file, how do i access it from the script?

Comment: recommendation?

Comment: @HazemAhmed - see my edit; btw, is this homework ?

Answer (score 2):

Using **`awk`** would be more appropriate for such case cause it should work even on non-GNU ***awk*** implementations:

```
awk '/^start/{ f=1 }f && /^next/ && getline nl>0{ print nl; exit }' test.txt
```

- `/^start/{ f=1 }` - set active flag `f=1` on encountering line `start`
- `f && /^next/ && getline nl>0` - on encountering `next` line (with previously matched `start` line - ensured by active `f` flag) - check if the next needed line exists with `getline nl>0`
- `nl` ("needed line") - contains the line following line `next`

---

The output (for your current input content):

```
This line should print
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `grep`? I will add explanation, if this command does, what you want.

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)start.*?next\n\K.*?\n' input.txt
```

**Input (your both examples merged)**

```
start
next
This line should print
Ignore this
Ignore this
next
Ignore this
start
Ignore this
next
This line should print
Ignore this
next
Too late so ignore this too 
start
Ignore this too
```

**Output**

```
This line should print
This line should print
```